# Boot Wubi in another bootloader

Tags: wubi, mac, bootloader, macbook-pro, refit

I have a MacBook Pro 9.2, with 2 partitions (3, considering Mac OS Recovery), one with MacOS X and another with Windows 8.
I have installed Ubuntu through Wubi in Windows and I'd like to, if possible, boot it directly from rEFInd (derives from rEFIt).
I tried adding

```
menuentry "Ubuntu" {
    icon \EFI\refind\icons\os_ubuntu.icns
    volume "BOOTCAMP"
    loader \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
}
```

but it gives me the error

```
Invalid loader file
Error: Not Found while loading wubildr.mbr
```

when I try to boot.
I got the boot info from easyBCD on Windows, which has the following entry:

```
Name: Ubuntu
BCD ID: {9c8f59fa-914f-11e2-98b8-e34e83468ecd}
Drive: C:\ Bootloader Path: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WUBI is a hackish way to boot Linux on a BIOS-mode PC.

A Windows installation on a Mac uses hackish tricks to get Windows booting in BIOS mode on an EFI-based computer.

Combine the two and you're using hackish tricks within hackish tricks to get Linux running.

In other words:

***Eeeuughhheee!!! (Shudder)***

In fact, triple-booting OS X, Windows, and Linux on a Mac is a bit of a nightmare, no matter how you do it. IMHO, the best way to tackle such needs generally involves using a virtual machine for at least one OS. That reduces the need for extreme expertise or weird shudder-inducing setups that will break the next time you look at it cross-eyed.

If you *must* triple-boot, I recommend starting over again:

1. Read [my page on hybrid MBRs,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) which will teach you about Apple's ugly and dangerous hack that's required to boot Windows Vista and earlier on Macs.
2. Check OS X forums for discussions of installing Windows in EFI mode on a Mac. This is possible, but difficult, with Windows 7. It's supposedly easier with Windows 8, but the details depend on your Mac model, and unfortunately, I don't have references to sites or forum threads discussing the matter, so I can't be more specific. If you can install Windows 8 in EFI mode, though, you'll obviate the need for the ugly and dangerous hybrid MBR and make the installation both much simpler and much more robust.
3. Read up on installing Linux in EFI mode. I wrote [a Web page on doing this on Macs](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/) that may be helpful, although it's a bit old and uses an ancient Mac as a reference. My more general page on [installing Linux on UEFI-based PCs](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi) may also be useful.
4. With this information in hand, redo your installation. At the very least, re-do the installation of Linux, reserving the hybrid MBR for Windows and booting Linux in EFI mode. Ideally, you'll be able to keep a legal protective MBR and boot all three OSes in EFI mode.

You'll note that these instructions are very general. This is because I'm advising you to learn about *your* specific computer and your specific needs, which I can't know. Triple-booting on a Mac is best accomplished via significant knowledge, not via a cookie-cutter recipe.

Oh, and your manual rEFInd boot stanza was doomed to failure because such stanzas can launch nothing but EFI programs, and the WUBI loader you're trying to launch is not such a program.